# fprintf stdout isn't dumping data 100% accurate

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdout

I've been using IAudioCaptureClient to collect data from my audio output device and record it into a file using mmioWrite that's working but I'd like to dump this data to stdout as well so I'd be able to stream it. I'm using fprintf but output data isn't quite the same as in the file that was written even though it was from the same buffer, the both files seems to be like 98% the same.

Here are the relevant code:

```
BYTE *pData;
...
// Here pData is bufferized with data from my output device
pAudioCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData, &nNumFramesToRead, &dwFlags, NULL, NULL);
...
LONG lBytesWritten = mmioWrite(hFile, reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(pData), lBytesToWrite);

fprintf(stdout, "%.*s", lBytesWritten, pData);
...
// I've also tried

// HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

// WriteConsole(hStdOut, reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(pData), lBytesWritten, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: `printf` `*` takes an `int`, not a `LONG`.

Comment: `stdout` is opened in text mode by default, so this stream will convert `\n` to `\r\n` in Windows. If your data might contain arbitrary bytes you'll have to do something about this, e.g. not use `stdout`, or reopen it in binary mode

Comment: that might be it, reopen stdin in binary mode, I'll search on how to do it

Comment: I was actually mistaken saying that the both files were like 98%, acctually they're quite different and printf miss a lot of information. It's like printf too slow and can't carry on with mmioWrite so I added a Sleep of 100 mili but it didn't solve the issue and it's not a multithread issue because they are running on the same thread so the text are not displaced from one to another. All the text in stdout is contained in mmioWrite but not otherwise.

Comment: ohh and I added `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);` to make a binary output of stdout but the result are the same.

Comment: In addition to the `\r\n` conversion, `fprintf` expects a `'\0'`-terminated string, so if there happens to be a zero byte somewhere the output will stop there.

Comment: Use `fwrite` instead. `fwrite(pData, 1, lBytesWritten, stdout);`, or the Windows specific `WriteFile` with the handle you get from `GetStdHandle`.

Comment: geza fwrite worked! if you want to add as an answer I will happily mark it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `fwrite` for writing binary data, you can control the number of bytes this way: `fwrite(pData, 1, lBytesWritten, stdout);`

In your example, `fprintf` stops printing data at the first zero terminator character (`lBytesWritten` width doesn't help here, it just controls padding). And if there is no zero terminators, it will print more, potentially inducing a crash.